# Stern-Stolz in $p$-adic case

Tags: p-adic-analysis, continued-fractions

I'm trying to figure out if the following statement is trivial or not:

> For $b_i \in \mathbb{C}_p$ (the complete $p$-adic field), if $\sum |b_i|_p < \infty$, then the continued fraction $b_0+\Large{K} \frac{1}{b_i}$ diverges.

On the one hand, convergence of a series in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is equivalent to the sequence limiting to zero and so I can prove the statement pretty quickly for $b_i \in \mathbb{Q}_p$. However, the valuations in $\mathbb{C}_p$ are $\mathbb{Q}$-valued. So I'm thinking that there actually is some work required to prove the statement in $\mathbb{C}_p$. But I still have this lingering feeling that I'm missing some sort of obvious point that makes the whole thing trivial.

Is it trivial, nontrivial, or already in the literature somewhere?

Comment: The equivalence of summability and zero-convergence has nothing to do with the discreteness of the valuation, only with its being non-Archimedean; our concern is just that small errors don't accumulate, not how we measure their smallness.

Comment: What in heaven's name is that gigantic $K$?

Comment: @znt: It's Gauss' Kettenbruch notation. See, for instance, https://oeis.org/wiki/Continued_fractions